# RoR app with Nginx + Puma on a sub uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, puma

I have a Ruby 1.9.3 on Rails 3.2 app running with Nginx + Puma + Capistrano 3 for dpeloy.

I followed some articles to do this setup mas seems I missed something.

My nginx.conf in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  upstream myapp {
    server unix:///home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server deferred;
    # server_name example.com;

    root /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/public;
    access_log /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

    location @myapp {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      if ($request_uri ~ "^((?!/portal))."){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /portal/$1 redirect;
      }

      proxy_pass http://myapp;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
  }
}
```

My puma.rb in config/puma.rb. I don't know if it's required to my app work because this config I found in others setups and tried to setup in my config. But seems that my deploy.rb have already these things setup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma
# start puma with:
# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C ./config/puma.rb

application_path = '/home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/shared/'
directory application_path
environment 'production'
daemonize true
pidfile "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{application_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect "#{application_path}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{application_path}/log/puma.stderr.log"
bind "unix://#{application_path}/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock"
```

So in Capistrano I create a symlink to my nginx.conf file. Here is the important things in my deploy.rb

```
set :repo_url,        '***'
set :application,     'www.myapp.com'
set :user,            'user'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stages,          %w(production staging)
set :default_stage,   "staging"
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/myapp.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
# set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false  # Change to true if using ActiveRecord

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

So when I restart Nginx I get my first problem comes: 403 Forbidden. Looking in my nginx.error.log I get this: *1 directory index of "/home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/public/" is forbidden. The user directory /home/user is with right permission (755) as far as I know.

And the second problem is how I setup to host everything in a sub url like www.myapp.com/portal? Because my entire website is already indexed with this suburi.

With Passenger I did this and worked but I could not with Puma:

```
...
server {
  listen            80 default_server;
  server_name       myapp.com;
  root              /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/public;
  rails_env         production;
  passenger_enabled on;

  location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ "^((?!/portal))."){
      rewrite ^/(.*) /portal/$1 redirect;
    }
  }

  location ~ ^/portal(/.*|$) {
    alias                   /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/public$1;
    passenger_base_uri      /portal;
    passenger_app_root      /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current;
    passenger_document_root /home/user/apps/www.myapp.com/current/public;
    passenger_enabled       on;
  }
...
```